# Como condicionar o select em outra linha da tabela no Mysql?

Tags: sql-select, mysql

Sou iniciante no que se refere à linguagem do MySql e estou tentando filtrar algumas informações que preciso retirar de uma tabela.

Basicamente eu tenho dados de indivíduos em anos seguidos (2003, 2004, 2005) todos em uma mesma tabela. Além desses dados, disponho de informações, por exemplo, da escolaridade (que pode mudar ano após ano, ou manter-se constante).

Porém alguns registros da minha base de dados são inconsistentes, por exemplo, selecionando os primeiros registros ordenados pelo cpf e pelo ano, temos (mudei o cpf por motivos de sigilo dos dados):

```
Ano      CPF        Escolaridade 
2004    10000000kkk 3
2005    10000000kkk 5
2003    10000000zzz 7
2005    10000000zzz 6
2003    10000000ttt 7
2005    10000000ttt 4
2004    10000000ppp 6
2005    10000000ppp 9
2004    10000000sss 7
2005    10000000sss 9
2005    10000000sss 9
2003    10000002xxx 6
2005    10000002xxx 7
```

A escolaridade é codificada:

```
ANALFABETO      1
ATE 5.A INC     2
5.A CO FUND     3
6. A 9. FUND    4
FUND COMPL      5
MEDIO INCOMP    6
MEDIO COMPL     7
SUP. INCOMP     8
SUP. COMP       9
MESTRADO        10
DOUTORADO       11
IGNORADO        -1
```

Minha dúvida é: como posso filtrar essas inconsistências? Alguém pode me ajudar? 
Já tentei alguns querys mas não funcionaram:

```
update `id2003to2005` set `chave_2`= concat( pis, grau_instr);

select
   k1.ano,  k1.grau_instr, k1.chave_2, k2.pis, k2.ano,  k2.grau_instr, k2.chave_2, k3.pis    
from id2003to2005 k1
   inner join id2003to2005 k2 on  k1.chave_2 != k2.chave_2 
   inner join id2003to2005 k3 on k2.pis=k3.pis 
where ((k1.ano - k2.ano=1) and ((k1.grau_instr - k2.grau_instr>1 or k1.grau_instr - k2.grau_instr<0))
    or ( (k1.ano - k2.ano>1) and (k1.grau_instr - k2.grau_instr>2 or k1.grau_instr - k2.grau_instr<0)))
```

Comment: que condição exatamente precisa, não ficou claro? não use o operador de não igual (`!=`)  no join, use apenas igualdade, se precisar fazer isso use o `where`

Comment: Ricardo eu preciso retirar da base todos os casos em que a escolaridade diminui de um ano para o outro ou que a escolaridade aumente de maneira não lógica (tipo a pessoa tem ensino fundamental em um ano e graduação no ano seguinte).

Answer (score 0):

Pegando o seu exemplo com o CPF "10000000zzz", a escolaridade em 2003 era maior do que em 2005.

```
2003    10000000zzz 7
2005    10000000zzz 6
```

Se você quer pegar este tipo de inconsistência, eu recomendaria você criar uma tabela temporária consolidado o último ano e nota

```
select MAX(ano) as ano, CPF, 0 as valor_atual, 0 as valor_anterior 
into tabela_temporaria
from minha_tabela group by CPF
```

Nesta tabela você tem o último ano do CPF. Com base nele, você vai atualizar a tabela temporária com a nota daquele ano

```
update tabela_temporaria set valor_atual = (SELECT escolaridade from minha_tabela WHERE ano = T.ano and CPF = T.CPF LIMIT 1)
from tabela_temporaria as T
```

E depois atualizar a temporária com a nota do primeiro ano anterior.

```
update tabela_temporaria set valor_anterior = (SELECT escolaridade from minha_tabela WHERE ano < T.ano and CPF = T.CPF ORDER BY ano DESC limit 1)
from tabela_temporaria as T
```

Comparando os dois valores você pode listar os CPFs com este tipo de inconsistência:

```
select * from tabela_temporaria WHERE valor_anterior > valor_atual
```

Comment: Vou tentar! É exatamente esse tipo de inconsistência que preciso remover, quando em períodos consecutivos a escolaridade diminui!
Muito obrigada!

Comment: Bins, tentei seguir sua ideia, mas, aparentemente, o update entre em um looping infinito e não chega à uma conclusão.